# R ggplot set colour for specific value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm doing multiple plots split by one variable and in each plot, colour code based on another variable.

```
set.seed(12345)
dates = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by = 1)
dd = data.table(date = dates, value = rnorm(length(dates)))
dd[, year := lubridate::year(date)]
dd[, c := cut(value, c(-Inf, -3, 3, Inf))]

for (thisyear in 2000:2015) {
  ggplot(dd[year == thisyear]) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(x = date, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = c), alpha = 0.1)
}

dd[, length(unique(c)), by = year]

   year V1
1: 2000  1
2: 2001  2
3: 2002  2
4: 2003  3
5: 2004  3
....
```

Now the colour in different plots will be inconsistent since not every year has the same length of unique cut values. Even worse is when one year has all `(-Inf,3]` values (unlikely here of course) and another year has all `[3,Inf)` values, they will both be coloured red in two plots.

How can I specify that `(-Inf, 3]` always take blue and `(-3,3]` always take green?

Comment: Do you mean `(3, Inf)` for the green colored points?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Is there an error in your `for`  loop, what is `thisyear` ?

Comment: There are a couple typos in the code: 1. `year in 2000:2015` should probably read `thisyear in 2000:2015`, and 2. `dd[year == thisyear]` should be `dd[year == thisyear,]`

Comment: Oops, thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 4):

One way to manually specify the colors to use, would be to simply create a column in your data frame specifying the plot color to use.

For example:

```
# scatter plot
dd$color <- ifelse(dd$value <= 3, 'blue', 'green')
ggplot(dd, aes(date, value)) + geom_point(colour=dd$color)

# ribbon plot
thisyear <- '2001'
dd_year <- dd[year == thisyear,]
ggplot(dd_year, aes(date, group=color, colour=color)) + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=value - 1, ymax=value + 1, fill=color), alpha=0.5) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=unique(dd_year$color)) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=unique(dd_year$color))
```

This would result in all points <= 3 being colored blue, and the remaining ones green.

Not the most interesting example perhaps since there is only only data point that gets colored green here, but it should look like this:

[image: ggplot2 colored ribbon plot]

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't seem to work with the `fill` property of `geom_ribbon`. You can either put `fill` in `aes` to have multiple colours, or a constant `fill` outside `aes`

Comment: Added a ribbon plot example.

Comment: The `geom_ribbon` code works because in 2000 the simulated data has only 1 cut group. It fails if you set `thisyear = 2001`

Comment: Good catch; I modified the code again and added output plot. Should work now.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a named vector of colors to pass to `scale_fill_manual`.  This allows you to choose the colors of each group as well as ensuring that each plot has the same colors among groups.

```
colors = c("blue", "green", "red")
names(colors) = levels(dd$c)

(-Inf,-3]    (-3,3]  (3, Inf] 
   "blue"   "green"     "red"
```

Now the same plot,  but with `scale_fill_manual` added.

```
for (thisyear in 2000:2015) {
    print(ggplot(dd[year == thisyear]) + 
        geom_ribbon(aes(x = date, y = value, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = c), alpha = 0.1) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = colors))
}
```